# How to create custom component in JavaFX and add it to toolbox?

Tags: javafx

How would I create a custom component in JavaFX 2.0 and make it available for drag'n'drop inside of a JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0?

I know how to create a new component, but i don't know how to make it appear inside of a javafx scene builder 2.0.

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm. After you create your node you have to make a jar. Add the jar to scenebuilder and add the java to your project path. You add the jar to scenebuilder and your project the same way you would add ControlsFX jar. You can search for info on how to do ControlsFX.

Comment: I couldn't follow the tutorial well, but I was able to download the source code using the link at the bottom of the page. Using the tutorial and the source code made things a lot clearer.